# How to extract email text in <a> tag nested in multiple divs using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, location-href

I am trying to use bs4 to extract this email, I've tried multiple methods and the output is still either none or blank.

```
<div> class = name 1
<div> class = name 2
    <div> class = name 3
        <div>
        <p> blah blah </p>
        <p>
            <a href = "mailto:email@email.com">
            email@email.com </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

this was my first attempt but I still receive nothing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import requests
import time

html = requests.get('https://soundcloud.com/camcontrast')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml') 

for a in soup.select('.infoStats__description p a'):
    print(a['href'], a.get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: Which one of the multiple methods were you most confident about? Share your code people will be able to help you.

Comment: Just shared code above

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup has a `find_all()` function that you could use for this purpose.
[Have a look at the find_all() documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

[And also the find_all() shortcut](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<div> class = name 1
<div> class = name 2
    <div> class = name 3
        <div>
        <p> blah blah </p>
        <p>
            <a href = "mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

"""

data = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for e in data.find_all('a'):
    print(e.string)
```

As an aside, you might want to check if the `class` text should be inside the `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `"select"` to extract email address from `<a>` tag: you can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc="""
<div> class = name 1
<div> class = name 2
    <div> class = name 3
        <div>
        <p> blah blah </p>
        <p>
            <a href = "mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

"""

data = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'lxml')
data = data.select('a')
for i in data:
    print(i.text)
```

Output will be:

```
email@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting all the `a tags` using `.find_all('a')` then filter out those having `mailto`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<div> class = name 1
<div> class = name 2
    <div> class = name 3
        <div>
        <p> blah blah </p>
        <p>
            <a href = "mailto:email@email.com">
            email@email.com </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>"""
```

---

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    if(link.get('href').find('mailto:') > -1):
        print(link.string.strip())
```

---

**Output:**

```
email@email.com
```

Comment: I want to use this but without have to call the actual text. I want it to be able to pull it directly from the website.

Comment: You have not given us the complete question then. This is the answer for your current post. Update the question then or better to ask a separate question.